# Gravitee 3.20 healthcheck locations

Tags: monitoring, healthcheck, helm, health

Maybe someone had a similar issue with healthchecking gravitee helm deployment - cannot find any endpoinds for the healthchecks. I had asked chatgpt and found documentation for it, but neither endpoints works - I get 404 not found:

`/_node/healthcheck` for each of - apim, gateway, portal, console

`/management/health` - for every service I get also 404

Both on service and public ports.

Thanks!